# nao_dcm_bringup problem

Tags: ros, moveit, nao-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, 
I am trying to use MoveIt! freamwork with Nao, but when i type the following command

```
roslaunch nao_dcm_bringup nao_dcm_H25_bringup_remote.launch
```

I got this

```
rocess[naoqi_dcm_driver-3]: started with pid [31698]
Could not find network interface named eth0, possible interfaces are ... enp0s31f6 lo 
[naoqi_dcm_driver-3] process has died [pid 31698, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/naoqi_dcm_driver/naoqi_dcm_driver __name:=naoqi_dcm_driver __log:=/home/lipadeadmin/.ros/log/a9641678-46ed-11e7-af09-484d7e9df0b0/naoqi_dcm_driver-3.log].
log file: /home/lipadeadmin/.ros/log/a9641678-46ed-11e7-af09-484d7e9df0b0/naoqi_dcm_driver-3*.log
[INFO] [1496337223.594046]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
```

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/nao_moveit_config)

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263004/nao_dcm_bringup-problem/) by [2fik](https://answers.ros.org/users/29515/2fik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have finally found a solution, i have sent an e-mail to the maintainers they said that i must add the "network_interface" parameter , bellow is the final command:

```
roslaunch nao_dcm_bringup nao_dcm_H25_bringup_remote.launch network_interface:="enp0s31f6"
```

---

Originally posted by [2fik](https://answers.ros.org/users/29515/2fik/) with karma: 20 on 2017-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0